# Mongolab connection not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I have a simple NodeJS service which uses mongodb. The thing is now I am "migrating" to mongolab insted of a local mongodb. The connection is working properly but when my service trys to retrieve some data, the following error apears:

```
{ [MongoError: auth failed]
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'auth failed',
ok: 0,
errmsg: 'auth failed',
code: 18 }
```

I've check some similar problems which and discarded the following isues:

- Is not the mongolab URL.
- Is not the mongolab database user (I am using admin/admin which has dbOwner role).

Server connection:

```
var db       = mongojs('mongodb://admin:admin@xxxxx.mongolab.com:xxxxx/database', ['players']);
```

Service

```
app.get('/player', function (req, res) {
    db.players.find().sort({_id:-1},function(err,docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

Comment: If you haven't already, write to support@mongolab.com for assistance. A common issue in these cases however is a node driver that is not compatible with MongoDB v3.0, specifically the SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication mechanism in MongoDB v3.0.

Comment: As you suggested, it had something to do with the SCRAM-SHA-1 auth mechanism in MongoDB v.30. The solution was to use that mechanism like this: `var db = mongojs('username:password@example.com/mydb', ['mycollection'], {authMechanism: 'ScramSHA1'})`. Thanks